# TabActivity that create an intent onClick button but the tabhost of activity receiver disappear

Tags: android, android-intent, android-tabhost, tabactivity

I have 2 activity: A, B. The first is an TabActivity and the second an Activity. 
Inside A i have a clickable button that make an intent to call the other activity.

```
public class A extends TabActivity implements OnClickListener {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        tabHost = getTabHost();
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("a").setContent(R.id.a).setIndicator("a"));

        b = new Intent(this,B.class);
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("b").setContent(b)
            .setIndicator(this.getString(R.string.b)));

        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if (arg0 == btn) {
        startActivity(b);
        }
    }
}
```

Inside B, i have a thread that gets data from internet every time that the button in A class is clicked:

```
public class B extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.search_result);

       searchHandler = new Handler() {
           @Override
           public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
               draw(msg.obj.toString());
           }
    }

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(..)
        sendHttpRequest();
}
```

Data returns correctly and I can manage it, but my tabhost disappear. How I can solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The android way to automatically change tab is:

```
tabHost.setCurrentTab(tab);
```

and not using:

```
startActivity(intent);
```

To use it on all your Activity the best way is to set your TabHost public and static.

Answer (score 0):

whenever you click a button you call an activity which is not child activity of tab activity.
so tabhost is disapear. call activity b in tab activity just like this

```
 tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab")
                    .setIndicator("Tab")
                    .setContent(new Intent(this, b.class)
                   ));
```

Comment: correct, but how can i have the behavior that i would like to have?

Comment: use tabchangedListener and on tabChanged method call you method.every time you change tab this method is called

Comment: I continue to don't understand how i can implement the workflow that i would. Only to be sure that you misunderstand me. I need to draw an activity associated to a tab B, but not clicking on the switch of tabs. Clicking on it, i only need to display what i have generated with a click on a button viewed on of the activity (A), but i would that the switch of tabs continue to be present.

If you think that your reply is still correct i would like more explanation.