# Trying to set an Intent in Android to a Tab

Tags: android

I'm working on my first Android project, and I'm trying to set a particular `intent` into a tab and i'm facing some severe issues.

Below is my code which creates each tab:

```
private void setupTab(final View view, final String tag, int imageId) {
    View tabview = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), tag, imageId);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyNewActivity.class);
    TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabview).setContent(intent);

    mTabHost.addTab(setContent);
}
```

I keep seeing the following stacktrace after the above function runs:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp/com.myapp.tabs.CustomTabActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
```

However, I read the following sites:

[TabActivity that create an intent onClick button but the tabhost of activity reciver disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437181/tabactivity-that-create-an-intent-onclick-button-but-the-tabhost-of-activity-rec)

[Adding an intent to a TabActivity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243078/adding-an-intent-to-a-tabactivity-in-android)

and it seems from the above that my code is correct? Is there something i'm missing?

**EDIT**

Made some progress...

Previously my TabHost as extending `Activity` but now I am extending `TabActivity` and it's going through...however my `Intent` is failing on the `onCreate` function on the line `setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);`

with the error:

addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView

I read the following for that:

http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html

It's using the same method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the link above (http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html), I was able to get this implemented.